# How to execute functions through the console of a running server build

Tags: unity

If I mark the "server build" check box in the building settings, build and then run the .exe, the game or in my case the server, will run as console with no graphics.

But what if I want for example, restart the server, without closing the window and executing the .exe again? Or what if I want for example kick a player?

Basically how I read what someone is typing in this console and execute a function from the build? Or how I do it, if anyone has a better approach. (Like the minecraft server does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use some local inter-process communication means such as sock files. This way you can log in to the device where the server is located to operate.
2. Develop a management background(a website maybe?), define some instructions, and operate the server in a graphical way. use remote process communication such as rpc, or define your own communication protocol, use tcp/udp/http.
3. Develop a console built into the game(Some games use chat as a base), assign permissions to players, send commands to the server using a common command sending protocol, and parse it yourself.
4. As for restarting the server, This is not an in-game function, it should be some scripts on the server or third-party process hosting software, such as supervisor.

For minecraft basically the third method is used, in the chat panel, special characters(`/`) are used to distinguish normal chat message and server commands.

Comment: Interesting, so to do something like minecraft I would have to use graphic mode instead of server build and make a chat, I think that this method is the easy one.

Comment: It's totally up to you. If the game is to be playable, a graphics client is required. If you want to achieve server online instead of host mode online, you must have a non-graphical server.